# If keywords in C# are not defined in, system class then where are they in the CLR?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I am a new leaner in C#.

I know the purpose of keywords in C#, and I know where keywords in C# are used, but it not defined in system class or any class then where is this in CLR, who is access, control and verify.

When execute the program these are all where it is stored memory in CLR.

Example:

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Console.writeline("Hello C# world ");
    }
}
```

In the above sample code:

Keywords are:

- public
- class
- static
- void
- main

Pre-defined class are:

- String
- Console

Classes are loaded through clr class loader.

But keywords where, when and who loaded.

Please let me explain me and don't reduce my point.

Comment: Some of the keywords are predefined, that means they are directly recognized by the compiler like class, public, void. Some of them are just an alias for some struct/class. eg- int, short, decimal. This ([MSDN C# Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)) might help you more.

Comment: If you want to know how any compiler works then check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis. If more interested then check Roslyn source for .net

Comment: `main` is not a keyword. Neither is `Main`. Also `String args[]` is bogus.

Comment: `void`, also, is not a keyword in conventional sense. It is `struct Void` in `System` namespace. You can check it by pressing F12 while cursor is on a `void`

Comment: @MehmetAtaş According to the MSDN link above `void` is a keyword. However, it is also an alias for `System.Void` which is why you can go to it using F12.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen That's why I added "in conventional sense"

Comment: @MehmetAtaş Well, there's no concept of conventional and unconventional keywords in the language spec. `void` is a keyword in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Keywords* are not defined in any assembly or the CLR. Rather, they are core parts of the language, and are supported directly by the compiler.

*Classes* are defined in assemblies. The `String` and `Console` classes happen to be defined in mscorlib.dll.